# Guild is showing undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am building my bot using discord.js (v13).

Here is my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const guild = require('../config.json');

module.exports = {
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('server')
    .setDescription('Display info about this server.'),

async execute(interaction) {

    const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#0099ff')
.setTitle(`Server infomation on ${guild.name}`)
.setDescription('Tells Server Info')
.addFields(
    { name: 'Server Name', value: `${guild.name}` },
    { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
    { name: 'Inline field titlve', alue: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
)
.setTimestamp()

    await interaction.reply({embeds: [exampleEmbed]}) ;
},
};
```

the above is an example of a slash command with an embed. In my embed, I am trying to print the guild name. Using guild.name. I don't get any error in the terminal but when I run the code in my discord server my bot shows undefined.

What am I doing wrong here and how do I fix it?

Edit: My Config.json:-

```
{
    "token": "Test Test",
    "clientId": "Client Id",
    "guildId": "Guild Id"
}
```

P.S. I am kinda new to discord.js and javascript

Comment: What's in your `config.json` file?

Comment: it contains my guild id token and client id

Comment: So it doesn't contain the `name`.

Comment: ofc, not my bot is going to be in multiple servers I don't want the bot to show the same server name for every server

Comment: Can you show us you `config.json`, it looks like that the property `name` is `undefined`.

Comment: If `guild` doesn't contain a `name` property then that's why `guild.name` returns undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `guild` is the content of the `config.json` file. If this file contains an object with the keys `guildID` and `clientID` only, `guild.name` will be `undefined`.

I think you want to use the `guild` where the `interaction` is coming from, in this case, it's [`interaction.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=guild):

```js
async execute(interaction) {
  const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle(`Server infomation on ${interaction.guild.name}`)
    .setDescription('Tells Server Info')
    .addFields(
      { name: 'Server Name', value: `${interaction.guild.name}` },
      { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
      { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
      { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .setTimestamp();

  await interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
}
```

Comment: You kinda made a typo it should be value not alue (line 9) but anyways it works thank you

Comment: Ah, I see, I haven't touched that part though, just copied from the question :) I'm glad it worked.